# Do i need a "Windows Subsystem for Linux" to deploy a python app to aws elastic beanstalk from windows OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was following a flask-tutorial on aws-docs and for windows OS it asked me to install "Windows Subsystem for Linux", but it worked for me without this.

I was able to deploy a hello world app to eb. any ideas why i need this subsystem and how it worked without it ? am on Windows 10/using Pycharm

Comment: can you please attach a link to the documentation where it says you need a "Windows subsystem for Linux"? Also, you are right in that you don't need anything special to deploy to EB from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For the AWS Beanstalk [Flask Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) you are given the option to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux. This is not required to actually create and deploy a Beanstalk application.

The Linux subsystem is for having access to a Linux like environment for development and testing. If your target environment is Linux, the Linux subsystem will be useful.